# send unicode strings via embeded forms in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, utf-8, character-encoding, wordpress-theming

I create a form in my wordpress theme that give data from users and save it in a table in database.
character encodings of wordpress theme is utf-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

but when i send data from another language it save in database in ????? format

please help me

Answer (score 0):

If your database table is not in UTF-8 as well then it will not save properly.

Can you make sure that the table you're inserting into is UTF-8?

Comment: and I use `echo mb_detect_encoding($_POST['fullname']);` to detect char set of my sending string and it echo UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Check `DB_CHARSET` in `wp-config.php`, it should be set to `utf8`.

PS : Not a collation problem

More about charset and collation :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-applications.html